# Why my environment variables work in common shell but not work in power shell in my windows system?

Tags: java, scala, shell, cmd

I am setting classpath in my `Windows` machine:

```
CLASSPATH = .;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%/tools.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\lib\scala-library.jar
```

When I open a terminal, type in `echo %classpath%`, it works well, but when open a `power shell` and type `echo %classpath%`, it can not print the environment.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell handles variables differently, try

```
Write-Output $Env:CLASSPATH
```

You can also use `echo $Env:CLASSPATH`, `echo` is just an alias for `Write-Output`.

Also interesting is

```
Get-ChildItem Env:
```

`Env:` is like a drive with all environment variables as children. More information on working with it can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx).